# Getx change object value in list not updating

Tags: flutter, dart

i have list of genre and i give a boolean property `'selected: false'` then if i click one of the genre it will turn to true if i select it again it will change to false. the problem is it's not updating the state, i already wrap it with obx and give .obs extension to the variable

note: the ui is Obx > Gridview.builder it's too many code so i shorten it

[image]

my code below

```
  selectPersonalize(item, index) {
    if (personalizeList[index]['selected'] == false) {
      personalizeList[index]['selected'] = true;
    } else {
      personalizeList[index]['selected'] = false;
    }

    log('Selected category ${personalizeList[index]}');
  }
```

the ui code

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          var item = personalizeController.personalizeList[index];
          bool selected = personalizeController.personalizeList[index]
                  ['selected'] ==
              true;

          return CustomImageBuilder(
            imageUrl: item['personalize_image'],
            placeHolder: const Skeleton(radius: 100),
            errorWidget: Icon(
              Icons.error,
              color: MyThemes.colorGrey,
            ),
            child: (imageProvider) {
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  personalizeController.selectPersonalize(item, index);
                },
                child: AnimatedContainer(
                  duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                        selected
                            ? MyThemes.colorBlue.withOpacity(0.1)
                            : Colors.black38,
                        BlendMode.darken,
                      ),
                      image: imageProvider,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 4,
                      color: selected
                          ? MyThemes.colorBlue
                          : Colors.transparent,
                    ),
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      item['personalize_description'],
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: MyThemes.colorWhite,
                        fontSize: 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
          );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the `selectPersonalize` function to this!

```
  selectPersonalize(item, index) {
     if (personalizeList[index]['selected'] == false) {
         personalizeList[index]['selected'] = true;
     } else {
         personalizeList[index]['selected'] = false;
     }
     personalizeList.refresh();
     log('Yeah. It is working!');
   }
```

Comment: WOOOOW thank you bro you really did save me, i don't know if there is a refresh artibute